# FineUploader 3.6.0 object File is not a File or INPUT element Ignoring

Tags: fine-uploader

I am trying to integrate fine uploader into my hybrid mobile app (using Icenium).  I have all the files needed and the uploader runs perfectly when I'm running the app in the simulator.  When I run my app on my iphone I get the [FineUploader 3.6.0] [object File] is not a File or INPUT element!  Ignoring!.  I can't for the life of me figure out why I would be getting this.

This is my config...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#fineUploader').fineUploader({
              request: {
                endpoint: 'uploadurl'
              }
            });
        });
```

I have navigated to the demo page for the jquery wrapper which uses the previous config and the demo runs fine.  Any ideas?  I'm not sure how to debug this any further.

Thanks

EDIT:

View -

```html
<div data-role="view" id="queue-view" data-title="Queue" data-show="app.queueView.show"     data-transition="slide:left" style="display: none;">
        <header data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <a data-align="left" data-icon="menuicon" data-role="button" data-click="app.applicationLayout.onMenuClick"></a>
                <span data-role="view-title"></span>
            </div>
        </header>
        <button id="filesButton">Add Files</button>
        <div id="fineUploader" class="upload-cont">
        </div>
        <div id="fineUploader2" class="upload-cont">
        </div>
        <input id="cameraButton" type="file" name="camera" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
    </div>
```

ViewModel (app.queueView.show) -

```js
$('#fineUploader').fineUploader({
              request: {
                endpoint: 'uploadurl'
              }
            });
```

I have also tried the direct from camera code which simply gives me undefined errors.  That's why there is an extra fineUPloader2 and the cameraButton.  I have tried a lot of things and all seem to result in either undefined errors or the No files error.

I'm also using require.js to bring in my javascript files (which I have many since I have set my project up using MVVM).

Thanks

Comment: What version of iOS?  Also, please show all of your code, including the HTML.

Comment: IOS 6.  I will add as much code as I think is needed as my project if very large.

Comment: What specific version of iOS, i.e. 6.x.x.  Also, confirm you are using Safari on iOS.

Comment: IOS 6.1.3.  I'm not using Safari directly as this is a hybrid html5 ios app (built using Icenium)  I believe it's using webkit to serve the html5 apps.  I know I may be using fineuploader in an unsupported way, but I didn't think I would run into any of these issues.

Comment: Based on the log message, I'm going to treat this as a bug and ask you to open up a bug report in the Github repo, where I can more easily have you try a few things to get to the bottom of this issue.  Please open up the bug here: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/new.

Comment: I've submitted the bug.  Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue was caused by a bug in Fine Uploader that appeared only when `File` objects are created in a frame/window/context other than the frame/window/context where the uploader instance was created.  There are a couple issues filed here.  Yours, ([#870](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/870)) and another, similar issue ([#866](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/866)).  The issue was caused by the use of `instanceof` to determine if an object was a `File`.  Both cited issues have been fixed in the associated hotfix branch in the Github project.  I plan on pushing out a 3.6.1 hotfix release with these fixes in the next 24 hours or so.